# /v1/requests/{request_id} incorrectly asks for requests scope

Tags: uber-api

I have the scope set with: all_trips profile

Webhook is successfully received on ride requests (non sandbox test) for a developer who authorized for the all_trips and profile scope.

When attempting to get the details for the trip - the api returns a 
{
    "message": "Missing scope: request",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}

From the documentation - I would assume that developers with all_trips shouldn't need request scope to "retrieve" status on trip - I see how it would be required to "request" a trip though....

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for "GET /v1/requests/{request_id}" matches your experience. You are required to have the `request` scope: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-details

> "Authorization: OAuth 2.0 bearer token with the request scope."

You can however use the requests/current endpoint (https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-current) which is available with the `all_trips` scope:

> "Authorization: OAuth 2.0 bearer token with the all_trips or request scope."

This was put in place because of concerns around historical data privacy. Re-examining this has alleviated those concerns however. We are going to relax this restriction shortly (likely within the next few weeks), and ease the scope restriction for 'details' to the same as 'current.' In the meantime, please use the current endpoint. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I was trying to query a completed/cancelled trip so the current would not have helped, but I will keep that in mind. With the sandbox, I've tested getting a trip start/end point / location, but wanted to test with real data :)